# How can an xinput command be run automatically when the system is started in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: bash, 18.04

I want this command to be executed automatically when my machine starts

```
xinput set-prop "AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint Stick" "Device Enabled" 0
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use **cron**
Edit `/etc/crontab` by using the command: `sudo gedit /etc/crontab` and add the following line to the bottom of the file:

```
@reboot     root   <your command>
```

Comment: not working for me